# C# datagridview cell with autocomplete LIKE

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to create a desktop application for my store.

My application currently using AutoComplete item like this screenshot shows:

[image]

Now I want to change that cell to autocomplete with `LIKE` function.

For example: my item list contains

```
["book", "brush", "pen", "samsung note 1", "samsung note 2", "samsung note 3", "samsung note 4"]
```

When I type "note", the autocomplete will suggest or show a list for me to pick the item.

But that list just contains "samsung note 1","samsung note 2", "samsung note 3", "samsung note 4", because this item has "note".

This is my code, an autocomplete without `LIKE` function

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{    
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        Connection.ConnectionClose();
        Connection.ConnectionOpen();

        //TODO fill Autocomplete list
        string queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM";

        Connection.command = new OleDbCommand(queryItem, Connection.conn);
        Connection.command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        AutoCompleteStringCollection kode = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        reader = Connection.command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                kode.Add(reader["code"].ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
        }

        reader.Close();

        //ComboBox txtBusID = e.Control as ComboBox;
        TextBox kodeTxt = e.Control as TextBox;

        if (kodeTxt != null)
        {
            kodeTxt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            kodeTxt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = kode;
            kodeTxt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        }
    }

    e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(AllowNumber_KeyPress);

    if (((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Assuming 0 is the index of the ComboBox Column you want to show
    {
        TextBox code = e.Control as TextBox;
        code.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;

        if (code != null)
        {
            code.Leave -= new EventHandler(cb_IndexChanged);
            // now attach the event handler
            code.Leave += new EventHandler(cb_IndexChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

i want change my autocomplete to able using "**LIKE**".

---

update using LIKE in Query.

```
 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            Connection.ConnectionClose();
            Connection.ConnectionOpen();
            int currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            //TODO fill Customer list
            string queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE CODE LIKE '%" + dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "%'";

            Connection.command = new OleDbCommand(queryItem, Connection.conn);
            Connection.command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection kode = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            reader = Connection.command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    kode.Add(reader["code"].ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data not Found");
            }
            reader.Close();
            //ComboBox txtBusID = e.Control as ComboBox;
            TextBox kodeTxt = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (kodeTxt != null)
            {
                kodeTxt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                kodeTxt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = kode;
                kodeTxt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            }

            }
}
```

and getting this error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   inventory.Market.SalesOrder.dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(Object
>   sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\vpc2\Documents\inventory\inventory\Market\SalesOrder.cs:line
>   922    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnEditingControlShowing(DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs
>   e)

---

i found that error come from `dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString()`

its look like i cannot get value when typing in datagridview's cell.

or i cannot get value when still on class `private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)`

---

i am trying to create something like this.https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251110/AutoComplete-TextBox-with-substing-search-similar

but not in textBox instead in datagridview's cell

Comment: Please only provide minimal relevant code in the question?

Comment: @zcui93 i already update my code, please help me.

Comment: @FrankM sorry, this line is for autocomplete `string queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM";`

Comment: What prevents you using `LIKE` in your query?

Comment: You could get the textvalue earlier ```TextBox kodeTxt = e.Control as TextBox;``` and the as zcui93 said use it in your SQL Query ```string queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE KODE LIKE '%"+kodeTxt.Text+"%'";```

Comment: @FrankM because i load all my item to autocomplete first, before form show.

Comment: @FrankM if i can do like, then am i possible to get the cell value when typing? see my image,

Comment: @zcui93 see my update

Comment: which line of code is on line 922

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 this line. ` string queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE CODE LIKE '%" + dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "%'";`

Comment: so what do you plan to do when dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value is null? obviously you are not expecting a crash?

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 no, i want to create something like this in my datagridview cell https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251110/AutoComplete-TextBox-with-substing-search-similar

Comment: so? what to do with null values in a cell (in a new row that is the default)?