# how to get datagridview's cell value in dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview.

row 1, column 1, i want to get this cell value when i am typing.

i tried this.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    int currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    Console.WriteLine("cell value on live = " + dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString());             
}
```

but i get this error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at inventory.Market.SalesOrder.dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(Object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) in c:\Users\anto\Jual\Market\Penjualan.cs:line 123

Comment: Why are you handling `EditingControlShowing` to do this? The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridvieweditingcontrolshowingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) say _"Handle the EditingControlShowing event to perform custom initialization of the editing control when a cell enters edit mode"_.

Comment: Plus, where does `currentRow` come from? What's its value when you debug the program?

Comment: @stuartd see this question,  i am trying to create a autocomplete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112025/c-sharp-datagridview-cell-with-autocomplete-like

Comment: @stuartd my bad, see my edit